# Defining a custom symbol by path in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, circuitikz

I want to define a 2-to-1 multiplexer symbol, defined by this path:

```
(0,0) -- (1,-0.5) -- (1,-1.25) -- (1.3,-1.25) -- (1,-1.25)-- (1,-2) -- (0,-2.5) -- (0,-1.75) -- (-0.3,-1.75) -- (0,-1.75) -- (0,-0.75) -- (-0.3,-0.75) -- (0,-0.75) -- (0,0)
```

As a new command, so that it's easier to use (as you can imagine, movement and scaling is borderline impossible). What would be the best way to do this?

For the record, this is just an example; I'm aware that this particular MUX is missing a select in.

Comment: You may want to check: https://github.com/gsarkis/tikz-mux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
  \newcommand\multiplexer[1][1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=#1]
  \draw (0,0) -- (1,-0.5) -- (1,-1.25) -- (1.3,-1.25) -- (1,-1.25)-- (1,-2) -- (0,-2.5) -- (0,-1.75) -- (-0.3,-1.75) -- (0,-1.75) -- (0,-0.75) -- (-0.3,-0.75) -- (0,-0.75) -- (0,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\begin{document}
 \multiplexer[0.2]

 This is a symbol: \multiplexer
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is good, but is there any way to have it positionable within an existing `tikzpicture` or `circuitikz` environment?

Comment: Never mind - figured it out. Thanks!

Comment: @Jules Could you explain what exactly you did to include it in a tikzpicture?

Comment: @Nijin22 sorry, can't remember off the top of my head, and my TeX-slinging days are pretty far behind me at this point. Have a [relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/979/), though.

Answer (score 1):

@Bobyandbob suggested I answer this.

The symbol can be drawn with `picture` and scale with optional parameter (thank you @PhelypeOleinik!).

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\newcommand{\mux}[1][1pt]{%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{#1}
    \begin{picture}(60,80)
        \put(20,20){\line(0,1){40}}
        \put(40,30){\line(0,1){20}}
        \put(20,20){\line(2,1){20}}
        \put(40,50){\line(-2,1){20}}
        \put(40,40){\line(1,0){6}}
        \put(20,30){\line(-1,0){6}}
        \put(20,50){\line(-1,0){6}}
    \end{picture}
}

\begin{document}

\mux

\mux[5pt]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice :) But you don't need `\scalebox`. You can change the size of a `picture` by changing the value of `\unitlength` with `\setlength{\unitlength}{<some amount>}`.

Comment: You're welcome :) You could also put the `<some amount>` as an optional argument to the `\mux` command, so you don't have to use `\setlength` every time :)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Even better - you are great!

Comment: Not so much. You did all the work, I just complained :D Nice job by the way

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik This website is very nice! I hope to stay!

Comment: That's great. Hope you enjoy your time here :)