# Does a symbol for glasses exist?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, symbols

I could not find the symbol of the image below which is in a book in my possession. I honestly do not remember where I saw it. Could someone help me where this symbol is located? This symbol (red rectangle) does not exist in the Comprehensive LATEX Symbol List by Scott Pakin.

[image]

Comment: just use `\includegraphics{zzz}` for any picture of glasses that you find with a google image search

Comment: @DavidCarlisle wouldn't be \includegraphics{looklooklook} be more fitting?

Comment: @Sebastiano if you have a book as paper you can not tell whether it is an image or a font glyph, why do you say it is not an image?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have used two tools on line **What Font Is** and **What The Font** and I have not find nothing. After I have searched on the web and I haven't find the same glasses.

Comment: @Sebastiano why do you think it is a font character?

Comment: This is not a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250511/is-there-a-latex-symbol-for-glasses?. It is older, but have less answers and popularity, so I mot sure of which questions should be closed.

Comment: @Fran I needed the pair of glasses of my image and not the ones with the moustache or modern style :-) is not a duplicate because I was asking if there was a precise font just for the glasses.

Comment: @Sebastiano Ok, he ask for a glasses symbol and not "that glasses symbol" but I will left the comment to maintain the link. I do not feel good cashing out Mr. Potato's decorations of a glasses party. `:)`

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Here is a Ti*k*Z solution.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\glasses}{\resizebox{3em}{!}{%
\tikz{\draw(0,0) coordinate (Origin) --++(0.2,0) coordinate (endL) arc (180:0:0.05)--++(0.2,0) coordinate (endR) --++(45:0.25) arc (180-45:0:0.08) (endR) arc (0:-180:0.1) (endL) arc (0:-180:0.1) (Origin)--++(45:0.25) arc (180-45:0:0.08);
}}}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\glasses\ \textsc{Attention}. \blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Spectacular, identical! Very good and excellent two times.

Comment: Spectacular… I *see* what you did there…

Answer (score 35):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzducks}

\begin{document}

\tikz{\duck[invisible,squareglasses]} 

\tikz{\duck[invisible,glasses]} 

\tikz{\duck[invisible,sunglasses]}  

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ducks may hide but they are still tasty.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle How can you target them with your fork if you don't see them?

Comment: @samcarter, attack in the middle of glasses to hit the head.... lol

Comment: NOW I know what the `invisible` option is good for. ;-)

Comment: I still see the ducks! One of them is smiling.

Comment: @thymaro Is the smiling duck the one with the sun glasses because it can enjoy the sun?

Comment: @samcarter I knew I wasn't the only one who could still see them!

Answer (score 30):

The unicode character `EYEGLASSES`, code `U+1F453`

seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: I would also like to thank you very much for your answer, which I am obviously voting for +1.

Comment: which fonts support this character?

Answer (score 22):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\begin{document}
\faGlasses\textsc{Attention:}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Marcel thank you very much for your answer. I am young, they seem used glasses :-). I do not like are too showy.

Comment: @Sebastiano If you own Font Awesome Pro, you can also use  [light] or [regular] glasses. They look much better with non-bold text.

Answer (score 14):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\noindent\includegraphics[height=1.5em]{zzz.png} \textsc{Attention} zzz
 z zzz zzz zzzzzzz  zzz z z z z zzzzz z z zzzzzzzzz zzz zzzz zzzzzzzz zzzzz.
\end{document}
```

where `zzz.png` is just a cropped version of the image you posted.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, but do not get angry with me politely. I'm not as good as you are but it's really ugly an image like this. It looks like a book from the '800 :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano yes but I cropped the image you posted, you could use a higher resolution scan of the original or as I said in the original comment use a google image search there are literally thousands of available line drawings you could use.

Comment: @Sebastiano An improved solution to David's would be to use a drawing software like Inkscape to trace the shape and convert it to a vector image. This should be rather easy with any similar software.

Comment: @Sebastiano This is the most general answer. Just google an image and use it. Or if you want something more fancy, search for fonts that have glasses as symbol (examples [here](http://www.fontspace.com/category/glasses)) and import that symbol probably with XeLaTeX).

Comment: @luchonacho I am writing a book together with a university colleague and there are many vector images. I was curious to know if there was a symbol of the glasses that I saw somewhere but I do not remember. Greetings.

Answer (score 12):

vector graphic = perfect quality

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[height=1em]{glasses.pdf} Attention!

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And where is `glasses.pdf` coming from?

Comment: @Arsenal On the web there are many vectorial pictures of glasses. It would be interesting to know where he found a beautiful vector image with glasses.

Comment: I looked for `glasses.pdf` on my computers. I didn't find it.

Comment: @thymaro That's strange, I can find it on my computer :)

Comment: Nice. I'll keep looking then. Maybe I'll rebuild the index.

Answer (score 12):

No images, no unicode characters, not tikz, no invisible ducks `:(`

[Macho programmers](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/225971/what-is-a-non-gendered-synonym-for-macho) use only ASCII. `:)`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\def\glasses{{\sffamily 
\leavevmode\rlap{%
\rotatebox[origin=tr]{125}{J}\kern1ex%  
\rotatebox[origin=tr]{125}{J}}% 
\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{D}%   
\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{D}}%
\def\ialy{\sffamily 
\resizebox{1ex}{1.5ex}{\reflectbox{\rotatebox[origin=]{75}{J}}}\kern-1pt%
\rlap{\tiny$\ ^\bullet\kern2.5pt^\bullet$ }%
\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{D}%   
\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{D}\kern-1pt%  
\resizebox{1ex}{1.5ex}{\rotatebox[origin=]{75}{J}}}}
\begin{document}
My pure \TeX(t) glasses \glasses\par
I am looking you \ialy
\end{document}
```

Comment: :-) ;-) double smiles for you and thank you very much to your answer +1.

Answer (score 7):

Without any packages

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{picture}(100,60)
\put(20,20){\line(1,1){20}}
\put(60,20){\line(1,1){20}}
\put(20,20){\line(1,0){17.5}}
\put(42,20){\line(1,0){17.5}}
\put(28.5,20){\oval(17.5,15)[b]}
\put(51,20){\oval(17.5,15)[b]}
\put(39.7,20){\oval(5,5)[t]}
\put(80,35.2){\oval(10,10)[rt]}
\put(40,35.2){\oval(10,10)[rt]}
\end{picture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! - Maybe you could go on with [Defining a custom symbol by path in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/164507/124842). Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Bobyandbob Thanks for welcome! About "Defining a custom symbol by path in TikZ": sorry, I don't know how scale :(

Comment: An option could be `\resizebox{0.5cm}{!} {
\begin{picture}(100,60)
...
\end{picture}
}`  - See [Is there a way to slightly shrink a table, including font size, to fit within the column boundaries?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10864/124842). If you can't solve it, you have to ask a new question.

Comment: @Bobyandbob I put answer to the "Defining a custom symbol by path in TikZ" question. Thank you for suggestion!